# Multiple Variables Javascript map() callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, map-function

I was doing some reading about es2015, trying out some of the examples on the arrow syntax when I came across this code:

```
var odds = evens.map(v => v + 1);//I understand
var nums = evens.map((v,i) => v + i);//I don't understand
```

with `evens` initialized to `[0,2,4,6]` I get `[1,3,5,7]` from `odds`, which I understand.

However I don't understand the result of the the second expression `[0,3,6,9]`. Essentially I'm not understanding what values are being assigned to the variable `i` in the second example. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Read the documentation for `Array#map`, in particular the part about what parameters it passes to the callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` function, will call the function passed to it with three parameters, as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap#Parameters)

- current element
- current element's index and
- the actual array itself

So, in your case, `v` is the current element and `i` is the index of the element in the array.

When `evens` is initialized with `[0, 2, 4, 6]`, it just adds the element with its corresponding index and returns a new array.